# How can I add an async function to a type def file?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add an async function definition to for async-busboy;

I have created a file "async-busboy.d.ts"

```
declare module 'async-busboy' {
    export default async function asyncBusby
        (subString: any): Promise<any>;
}
```

But this gives me the error: *"error TS1040: 'async' modifier cannot be used in an ambient context."*

How do I write async function defs?
Thanks

EDIT
Thanks @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir and @Aaron for your answer. But when I call it I get an error

```
const dddd = await asyncBusboy(22);
[ts] 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you aren't calling async code from an async function, you can use the returned promise (instead of `await`ing a value). `asyncBusboy(22).then((dddd) => { alert(dddd); });`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
declare module 'async-busboy' {
    export default function asyncBusby
        (subString: any): Promise<any>;
}
```

The fact that it returns a `Promise` is what makes it of async type (nothing related to the `async` modifier). Consumers are expected to `await` the `any` value now.

On the other hand, the `async` modifier is used to augment the function (body) ***implementation*** (what it returns becomes wrapped in a promise). Since the type-def doesn't deal with the implementation, therefore the `async` isn't allowed in the type-def.

In other words, from the perspective of the method/function interface the `async` modifier is not saying/changing anything and therefore is ***not needed*** in the interface declaration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the `async` modifier in a declaration. The `async` modifier directs the compiler to emit code enabling use of `await`. From the point of view of the consumer the important part is that it returns a `Promise` not how the async is implemented in the body of the function. You can consider `async` an implementation detail of the function.

Your problem is a call site issue, you need to mark the function in which you call `asyncBusby` as being `async`:

```
async function foo (){
    const dddd = await asyncBusby(22);
    console.log(dddd);
}
```

Comment: @dewijones92 Updated the answer